# Does falling count as part of my movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, falling

I'm new to D&D.  I've read certain answers to questions similar to mine, but I wish further clarification.

If I, as a Winged Tiefling, fall onto an opponent as part of an attack, **does the distance I fall deduct from my movement distance tally?**

#### Example

I have a speed of 30 feet, and I'm 15 feet over an opponent.  I wish to fall onto him, using my body weight as a weapon.  I then want to move 15 feet, cast a spell as an action, then move 15 (or Dash 30) feet as a Bonus Action and cast a Cantrip.

Would the falling 15 feet, as it's unwilling movement, cost me movement, thus removing the second part of my movement phase?

Comment: Related: [If an object or creature is dropped on a monster, how much damage does each of them take?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70529/28591)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it's in the scenario you described - you cannot cast a non-cantrip spell as an action in any turn in which you cast any bonus action spell.

Answer (score 8):

Falling does not use up your movement speed, no.

However, be aware that rules-as-written you're going to take bludgeoning damage when you land (1d6 per 10 feet of falling). If you are using the optional falling rules from [Chapter 2 of Xanathar's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#Falling) for falling very large distances, then you will descend at 500 feet per round.

I don't believe there are explicit mechanics for handling deliberately falling onto a creature, you'll have to work that out with your DM.

Comment: You also fall prone, which is relevant for wanting to move away.

Comment: It would be worth backing up the (correct) assertions in this answer with relevant quotes from the rules.

Comment: @nitsua60 Absolutely...though if you use D&D Beyond as the main source for rules text, you don't have page numbers, and avoiding link rot becomes more of a priority.

Comment: That raises a question though. What if you drop 500 feet by not flying any more. Then when you are 5 feet from the ground you resume flying and use 5 feet of your flight movement to reach the ground? D&D has no concept of momentum so in theory you take no falling damage.

Comment: @AllanMills ask it as a new question!